# Undefined symbol 'fixed_address_empty_string' : new tensorflow op with protobuf

Tags: c++, tensorflow, shared-libraries, protocol-buffers

I would like to create a new operation that can communicate to an
external python process. At the momemnt, I created a new operation
that sends to a python process "hello world" with `protobuf`.

In this tiny example, I'm sending a string. In the future I would like
to send more complex data, like Eigen matrices, that's why I chose
`protobuf`. (and for possible 'easy integration into tensorflow).

**msg.proto** :

```
package prototest;

message Foo {
  required string bar = 1;
}
```

- `protoc msg.proto --cpp_out=. --python_out=.`
- generates : `msg.pb.cc  msg.pb.h  msg_pb2.py`

**hello_world.cc** :

```
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_shape.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/platform/default/logging.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/shape_inference.h"

// to send serialized data through UPD socket
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

// generated header file from protoc
#include "msg.pb.h"

namespace tensorflow{
    namespace shape_inference{

        Status HelloWorldShape(InferenceContext* c){
            std::cout << "shape_infernce is done" << std::endl;
            return Status::OK();
        }
        REGISTER_OP("HelloWorld")
            .SetShapeFn(HelloWorldShape)
            .Doc(R"doc(HelloWorld operation)doc");
    } // end namespace shape_inference

    class HelloWorldOp : public OpKernel {
    public :
        // constructor
        explicit HelloWorldOp(OpKernelConstruction* context) : OpKernel(context) {
            std::cout << "HelloWorldOp constructor" << std::endl;
        }

        void Compute(OpKernelContext* context) override {
            std::cout << "Start Compute method" << std::endl;
            //-----------------------------------------------------------------
            // send something to a Python process with protobuf
            struct sockaddr_in addr;
            addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
            inet_aton("127.0.0.1", &addr.sin_addr);
            addr.sin_port = htons(5555);

            // initialise a foo and set some properties
            GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_VERIFY_VERSION;

            prototest::Foo foo;
            foo.set_bar("Hello World");

            // serialise to string, this one is obvious ; )
            std::string buf;
            foo.SerializeToString(&buf);

            int sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
            sendto(sock, buf.data(), buf.size(), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));
            //------------------------------------------------------------------
            std::cout << "Compute method is done" << std::endl;
        }
    };
    REGISTER_KERNEL_BUILDER(Name("HelloWorld").Device(DEVICE_CPU), HelloWorldOp);
} // end namespace tensorflow
```

To compile and run my code, I use a test scrip found at [#10950](http://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10950)

**compiler_and_run.py** :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.5

# Demo from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10950

from __future__ import print_function
import os
import sys
import tensorflow as tf


my_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
so_filename = "lib_hello_world.so"
cc_filename = "hello_world.cc"


def compile():
    # Fix for undefined symbol: _ZN6google8protobuf8internal26fixed_address_empty_stringE.
    # https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1419
    from google.protobuf.pyext import _message as msg
    lib = msg.__file__
    ld_flags = [
        "-Xlinker", "-rpath", "-Xlinker", os.path.dirname(lib),
        "-L", os.path.dirname(lib), "-l", ":" + os.path.basename(lib)]
    common_opts = ["-shared", "-O2", "-std=c++11"]
    if sys.platform == "darwin":
        common_opts += ["-undefined", "dynamic_lookup"]
    common_opts += ["-I", tf.sysconfig.get_include()]
    common_opts += ["-fPIC"]
    common_opts += ["-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0"]  # might be obsolete in the future
    opts = common_opts + [cc_filename, "-o", so_filename]
    opts += ld_flags
    cmd_bin = "g++"
    cmd_args = [cmd_bin] + opts
    from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT, CalledProcessError
    print("compile call: %s" % " ".join(cmd_args))
    proc = Popen(cmd_args, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
    stdout, stderr = proc.communicate()
    assert stderr is None  # should only have stdout
    if proc.returncode != 0:
      print("compile failed: %s" % cmd_bin)
      print("Original stdout/stderr:")
      print(stdout)
      raise CalledProcessError(returncode=proc.returncode, cmd=cmd_args)
    assert os.path.exists(so_filename)


def main():
    print("TensorFlow version:", tf.GIT_VERSION, tf.VERSION)
    os.chdir(my_dir)
    compile()
    mod = tf.load_op_library("%s/%s" % (my_dir, so_filename))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This returns :

```
TensorFlow version: v1.2.0-rc2-21-g12f033d 1.2.0
compile call: g++ -shared -O2 -std=c++11 -I /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/include -fPIC -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 hello_world.cc -o lib_hello_world.so -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/protobuf-3.2.0-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/google/protobuf/pyext -L /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/protobuf-3.2.0-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/google/protobuf/pyext -l :_message.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./compile_and_test.py", line 55, in <module>
    main()
  File "./compile_and_test.py", line 51, in main
    mod = tf.load_op_library("%s/%s" % (my_dir, so_filename))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/load_library.py", line 64, in load_op_library
    None, None, error_msg, error_code)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: /src/ext_hello_world/lib_hello_world.so: undefined symbol: _ZN6google8protobuf8internal26fixed_address_empty_stringE
```

Compilation seems to work (no fatal error). But `tf.load_op_library()` fails due to undefined library in shared lib (*.so).

This undefined symbol seems to come from protobuf.

I installed `protoc` by myself (see Note about it).

In `tf.sysconfig.get_include()` there is a  `google/protobuf` folder with header files from built tensorflow.

So I don't know which header files are used during compilation :
 - header files from include files of tensorflow ?
 - header files of hand-installed protobuf ?

Or this undefined symbol is not due to this fact ?

- How can I resolve this undefined symbol error in the shared library ?
- May I have to install `protoc` starting from `tensorflow/includes/google/protobuf` ? (and not from scratch)

I observed that in [#10950](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10950) :

```
from google.protobuf.pyext import _message as msg
lib = msg.__file__
```

returns : `/u/zeyer/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/protobuf/pyext/_message.so`

In my case it's : `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/protobuf-3.2.0-py3.5-linux-x86_64.egg/google/protobuf/pyext/_message.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`
This file about protobuf seems to be completely different ...

**Note about protoc install** :
`protoc` (protobuf compiler) was not installed.
I identified the version of protobuf used in tensorflow : v3.2.0 !

After, I followed protobuf installation instruction (C++ and Python implementation).

```
cd /opt/
# clone protobuf repo
git clone https://github.com/google/protobuf.git
cd protobuf

# change to the right branch
# list tags
git tag -l
git checkout tags/v3.2.0

# install protobuf
apt-get install autoconf automake libtool curl make g++ unzip
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
make check
make install
ldconfig

# protoc version
protoc --version
>>> libprotoc 3.2.0

# print linker and compiler files
pkg-config --cflags --libs protobuf
>>> -pthread -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lprotobuf -pthread -lpthread

#some useful env variables
PB_INC=$(pkg-config --cflags protobuf)
PB_LINK=$(pkg-config --libs protobuf)
TF_INC=$(python3.5 -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.sysconfig.get_include())')
TF_LIBS=$(find $TF_INC/../ -name "*.so")

# here, I used python3.5
cd python
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=../src/.libs
python3.5 setup.py build --cpp_implementation
python3.5 setup.py test --cpp_implementation
python3.5 setup.py install --cpp_implementation
```

#### System information

- docker : Docker version 1.12.6, build 78d1802
- image : tensorflow/tensorflow:1.2.0-devel-gpu-py3
- based on : ubuntu 16.04 (4.4.0-78-generic)
- tensorflow build from source
- tensorflow version : 1.2.0
- python version : Python 3.5.2
- bazel version :

  `Build label: 0.4.5
  Build target: bazel-out/local-fastbuild/bin/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/BazelServer_deploy.jar
  Build time: Thu Mar 16 12:19:38 2017 (1489666778)
  Build timestamp: 1489666778
  Build timestamp as int: 1489666778`
- gcc -v :
  ```
  Using built-in specs.
  COLLECT_GCC=gcc
  COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/lto-wrapper
  Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
  Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-5 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-5-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
  Thread model: posix
  gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4)

Information from https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tools/tf_env_collect.sh :

```
== cat /etc/issue ===============================================
Linux 2b98f5ebc987 4.4.0-78-generic #99-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 27 15:29:09 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
VERSION="16.04.2 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial

== are we in docker =============================================
Yes
== compiler =====================================================
c++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

== uname -a =====================================================
Linux 2b98f5ebc987 4.4.0-78-generic #99-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 27 15:29:09 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
== check pips ===================================================
numpy (1.13.0)
protobuf (3.3.0)
tensorflow (1.2.0)

== check for virtualenv =========================================
False
== tensorflow import ============================================
tf.VERSION = 1.2.0
tf.GIT_VERSION = v1.2.0-rc2-21-g12f033d
tf.COMPILER_VERSION = v1.2.0-rc2-21-g12f033d
Sanity check: array([1], dtype=int32)
== env ==========================================================
LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64:/usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH is unset
== nvidia-smi ===================================================
Wed Aug 23 17:24:13 2017
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 370.28                 Driver Version: 370.28                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce 940MX       Off  | 0000:01:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   54C    P0    N/A /  N/A |    277MiB /  2002MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

== cuda libs  ===================================================
/usr/local/cuda-8.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudart_static.a
/usr/local/cuda-8.0/targets/x86_64-linux/lib/libcudart.so.8.0.61
```

Answer (score 0):

It is from linking against the dll libraries, libprotobuf[d].lib, without specifying -DPROTOBUF_USE_DLLS.

See 'DLLs vs. static linking' in the readme for further information.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think TensorFlow exports enough symbols to rely on it for a protocol buffer implementation. Rather, you can dynamically link against the system protocol buffer implementation you've installed. This may need to match the TensorFlow protocol buffer version to avoid symbol conflicts.

I'm testing with TensorFlow 1.3.0 (Python 3.4), using libprotoc 3.3.0. I've added `msg.pb.cc` (the output of `protoc msg.proto --cpp_out=. --python_out=.`) to the compilation command (which links in the C++ implementation of your message), along with the output of `pkg-config --cflags --libs protobuf` in order to link against the system protocol buffer library. This procedure works for me:

```
protoc msg.proto --cpp_out=. --python_out=.
g++ -shared -O2 -std=c++11 -I /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tensorflow/include -fPIC -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 hello_world.cc msg.pb.cc -o lib_hello_world.so $(pkg-config --cflags --libs protobuf)
python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; tf.Session().run(tf.load_op_library('./lib_hello_world.so').hello_world())"
```

Since you've serialized the protocol buffer, there should be no issue deserializing it in Python; the minor protobuf versions shouldn't need to match since it's in wire format.